# reactjs ajax DOES NOT show options

Tags: c#, ajax, reactjs

I tried to use reactjs work with C# MVC, and i want to use reactjs ajax to get json array from controller,then show the array elements into select options. But if i use local array, it could show in the select options. I can print out the array element when i use ajax query server method. I do not what happenend.

My view:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-2" id="select">
      </div>
</div>

<script type="text/babel">

            var Groups = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function () {
                    return {
                        data: []
                    };
                },

            componentDidMount: function(){
                this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.rout, function(response){
                    this.setState({
                        data: response
                    });
                }.bind(this));
            },

            componentWillUnmount: function(){
                this.serverRequest.abort();
            },

            render () {

                return (<select className="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" title="Choose 2-4 colors" data-live-search="true">
                    {this.state.data.map(function (x) {
                            console.log(x);
                    return <ABC value={x}  />;


                    })}
                    </select>);
                }
            });

            var ABC = React.createClass({
                render: function(){
                    console.log("Option");
                    console.log(this.props.value);
                    return <option value={this.props.value}>{this.props.value}</option>;
                }
            });

            ReactDOM.render(
                    <Groups rout="/CodingManagement/Notification/GroupName" />,
                document.getElementById('select')
            )

    </script>
```

I could see the console result, but it does not show in view. But if i pass the array to {data}, it could show in the view.

Like this one, it works. I do not know why

```
<script type="text/babel">

var Groups = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: this.props.rout
        };
    },

    render () {
        console.log("Groups");
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (<select className="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" title="Choose 2-4 colors"
                        data-live-search="true">
            {this.state.data.map(function (x) {
                return <ABC value={x}/>;


            })}
        </select>);
    }
});

var ABC = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        console.log("Option");
        console.log(this.props.value);
        return (
                <option value={this.props.value}>{this.props.value}</option>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
        <Groups rout={["Group4", "Group1", "Group11"]}/>
    ,
    document.getElementById('select')
);
```

This is server code

```
public JsonResult GroupName()
    {

        string[] group = new string[] { "Group4", "Group2", "Group3" };
        return Json(group, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on console?

Comment: I got warning in both ways.            Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Groups`. 
    in ABC (created by Groups)
    in Groups                                       i think this warning is from different reactjs package. When i change cdn to react.min.js and react-dom.min.js, warning is disappear. But it still does not show options in my view

Comment: Not a React dev. Check if you're expecting an `array` in your front end (vs an object containing an array).

Comment: Did you try using `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` ?

Comment: Tried, but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you try to add a console.log(response) in your componentDidMount to see if it is a Json is exactly an array? I doubt it will be an object type and not a array with the groups only. I guess you need to use response.body to get the content.